# How to load data as text file in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How can I load data as text file in "file" column in mysql table?

If my table is: id,name,file

I don't want to use text file to load data in my table, I want to store the actual .txt files in my table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name.txt'
INTO TABLE database.table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ENCLOSED BY ''
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STARTING BY ''
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not storing data from the .txt file into the table?

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/foo.txt' 
INTO TABLE foo COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t';

Comment: Your answer is not accepted, you did not answer the question